# AspectJ: this and target context

Tags: java, aspectj

I am using aspectj for analysis of my program. Currently my aspect looks like:

```
@Aspect
public class InvokeAspect {
    @Before("anyCall(t, s)")
    public void processInvocation(JoinPoint point, JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart enclosingStatic, Object t, Object s){
        System.out.println("***");
        System.out.println("Invoker: " + s.toString());
        System.out.println("Invoker: " + enclosingStatic.getSignature().toLongString());
        System.out.println("Invoked object: " + t.toString());
        System.out.println("Invoked: " + point.getSignature().toLongString());
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("***");
    }
    @Pointcut("call(* *(..)) && !within(cz.cvut.kbss.odra..*) && target(t) && this(s)")
    public void anyCall(Object t, Object s){}
}
```

Everything works as expected, but is there any way to convice aspectj to use the aspect, even if **this** or **source** do not exist? (static method call or call from static method). Or do I have to write 3 aspects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think you will have to write three pointcuts - one along the lines of what you have, second a call from a static method and the third for a call from an object to a static method, probably three different advices also, delegating to the `processInvocation` method above

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with one pointcut + one advice if you are willing to determine your `target` and `this` objects dynamically. I am writing this in AspectJ syntax because I do not feel comfortable with the POJO annotation style:

```java
public aspect InvokeAspect {
    pointcut anyCall() : call(* *(..)) && !within(cz.cvut.kbss.odra..*);

    before() : anyCall() {
        Object s = thisJoinPoint.getThis();
        Object t = thisJoinPoint.getTarget();
        // and so forth
    }
}
```

Now you can print or log whatever seems appropriate to you. Take care of checking `s` and `t` for null values if you want to call methods such as `toString()` upon them.

Comment: @malejpavouk: If you agree with me that the proposed solution is what you asked for, I would be happy if you accepted my answer.